# Tildes con Python

Tags: python, cmd

Ayer estaba ejecutando un script en python y las tildes se mostraban como caracteres extraños. Hoy ejecute el mismo script sin cambiar nada y ahora si se muestran correctamente las tildes. ¿Por qué?

A continuación los archivos que conforman mi programa, el cual es para convertir sistemas numéricos:

main.py

```
from convert import *
from utils import *

def main():
    menu()
    try:
        opcion = int(input("Mi opción es: "))
        limpiar()
    except ValueError:
        limpiar()
        print("Usted ha escrito algo más que números.")
        print("")
        main()
    if opcion == 1:
        binario_decimal()
    elif opcion == 2:
        binario_hexadecimal()
    elif opcion == 3:
        decimal_binario()
    elif opcion == 4:
        decimal_hexadecimal()
    elif opcion == 5:
        hexadecimal_binario()
    elif opcion == 6:
        hexadecimal_decimal()
    elif opcion == 7:
        return 0
    else:
        print("La opción no existe.")
        print("")

    main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    limpiar()
    main()
```

utils.py

```
import platform
import os
 
def limpiar():
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        return os.system("cls")
    else:
        return os.system("clear")
 
def invertir(texto):
    contador = len(texto) - 1
    salida = []
 
    while contador > -1:
        salida.append(texto[contador])
        contador -= 1
 
    return "".join(salida)
 
def list_sum(lista):
    contador = 0
    salida = 0
 
    while contador < len(lista):
        salida += lista[contador]
        contador += 1
 
    return salida
 
def menu():
    print("Conversión de sistemas numéricos")
    print("")
    print("1) Binario Decimal")
    print("2) Binario Hexadecimal")
    print("3) Decimal Binario")
    print("4) Decimal Hexadecimal")
    print("5) Hexadecimal Binario")
    print("6) Hexadecimal Decimal")
    print("7) Salir")
    print("")
```

convert.py

```
from utils import *
 
def binario_decimal():
    def validar(binario):
        contador = 0
        numero_actual = 0
        cifras = [0, 1]
        while contador != len(binario):
            numero_actual = int(binario[contador])
            if numero_actual in cifras:
                contador += 1
                continue
            else:
                return False
        return True
 
    def convertir(binario):
        contador = 0
        numero_actual = 0
        valor_posicion = 1
        suma = []
        while contador != len(binario):
            num_actual = int(binario[contador])
            if num_actual == 1:
                suma.append(valor_posicion)
                valor_posicion *= 2
            else:
                valor_posicion *= 2
            contador += 1
        resultado = list_sum(suma)
        return resultado
 
    print("Conversión de binario a decimal")
    print("")
 
    try:
        numero = int(input("Escriba el numero binario para convertir: "))
        limpiar()
    except ValueError:
        limpiar()
        print("Usted ha escrito algo más que números.")
        print("")
        return 0
 
    numero = str(numero)
    numero = invertir(numero)
 
    if validar(numero) == True:
        decimal = convertir(numero)
        numero = invertir(numero)
        print("El numero binario " + str(numero) + " representado en el sistema numerico decimal es " + str(decimal) + ".")
        print("")
        return 0
    else:
        print("El numero especificado no era binario.")
        print("")
        return 0
 
def binario_hexadecimal():
    print(" =====================================")
    print("| Conversion de binario a hexadecimal |")
    print(" =====================================\n")
 
    numero = int(input("Escriba el numero binario para convertir: "))
 
    limpiar()
 
def decimal_binario():
    print(" =================================")
    print("| Conversion de decimal a binario |")
    print(" =================================\n")
 
    numero = int(input("Escriba el numero decimal para convertir: "))
 
    limpiar()
 
def decimal_hexadecimal():
    print(" =====================================")
    print("| Conversion de decimal a hexadecimal |")
    print(" =====================================\n")
 
    numero = int(input("Escriba el numero decimal para convertir: "))
 
    limpiar()
 
def hexadecimal_binario():
    print(" =====================================")
    print("| Conversion de hexadecimal a binario |")
    print(" =====================================\n")
 
    numero = int(input("Escriba el numero hexadecimal para convertir: "))
 
    limpiar()
 
def hexadecimal_decimal():
    print(" =====================================")
    print("| Conversion de hexadecimal a decimal |")
    print(" =====================================\n")
 
    numero = int(input("Escriba el numero hexadecimal para convertir: "))
 
    limpiar()
```

Sé que el código es enredado, pero lo que importa son las instrucciones de funciones `print()`.

Comment: Cuál script? Cuáles carácteres? Es difícil responder sin adivinar

Comment: @Alfabravo Las letras con tildes se mostraban mal. Con "un script" me refiero a un programa de python muy básico que sólo convierte números binarios a decimales.

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿Será porque Windows es chatarra? Jajajaja.

Comment: A ver: no es posible darte una respuesta sin que nos MUESTRES el script y los caracteres extraños. Como está ahora mismo esta pregunta, es un ejercicio de adivinación y va a terminar cerrada.

Comment: @Alfabravo No puedo mostrar los caracteres extraños porque hoy no salen, pero si indicaba que se escribiera por ejemplo á, salía algo así como a[ü. Ya paso el script, aunque sé que no es necesario para la pregunta.

Comment: Ayer estaba usando Windows para ejecutarlo y en el cmd se mostraban caracteres extraños en lugar de letras con tilde, por lo que trasladé el proyecto a Debian, porque ahí si no hay errores, Esta mañana volví a ejecutar el programa en Windows y sí se mostraban las tildes correctamente.

Comment: Listo, ya puse el código en la pregunta, borraré los links...

Comment: podrías agregar al inicio de los scripts: #-*- coding: utf -8 -*- para evitar errores por caracteres con acentos o ñ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh si, bienvenido al maravilloso mundo de manejo de UTF formatting...

Cuanto manejo manual debes hacer dependerá del contexto. No entendí totalmente si el problema es cuando estás imprimiendo (en la consola?) o si es sobre como se muestran al usuario los strings que tienes dentro de tu script.

En fin, sea la situación que sea, cuando trabajamos con I/O de texto afuera del alfabeto inglés a veces tenemos estos problemas. Lo que más molesta es que diferentes plataformas pueden mostrar diferentes comportamientos (windows vs linux vs mac), pero como programador debes asegurarte que cubras todos los casos.

La [documentación de python](https://docs.python.org/es/3.7/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support) ya nos dice directamente como hacerlo. Usar `encode()`/`decode()`. Fun fact: En python 3, todos los string son unicode por default (esto no era así antes). Aquí un par de cosas que puedes intentar en tu consola para entender mejor lo que está sucediendo (mi consola está linux, en windows probablemente será distinto, sería genial si lo agregas en los comentarios para confirmar):

```
>>> mistr = "Hola ñonos, me gustan los . Я также говорю по-русски."
>>> print(mistr)
Hola ñonos, me gustan los . Я также говорю по-русски.
>>> encoded8 = mistr.encode('utf-8')
>>> print(encoded8)
b'Hola \xc3\xb1onos, me gustan los \xf0\x9f\x8c\xae. \xd0\xaf \xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x8e \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe-\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8.'
>>> print(encoded8.decode('utf-8'))
Hola ñonos, me gustan los . Я также говорю по-русски.
>>>
```

Al menos en mi sistema no es necesario manejar el str. Pero si fuese a asegurar que mi programa corre en todos lados, entonces guardaría el string con el "encoding" inmediatamente al recibirlo, y haria el "decoding" solo cuando lo necesite mostrar al usuario. Eso indicaría a todo sistema cómo manejar el string independiente de como lo haga por default.

Por cierto puedes hacer esto con otros tipos de encoding (existen muchos). pero UTF-8 y UTF-16 son los más utilizados en el día a día.

```
>>> mistr.encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfeH\x00o\x00l\x00a\x00 \x00\xf1\x00o\x00n\x00o\x00s\x00,\x00 \x00m\x00e\x00 \x00g\x00u\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00 \x00l\x00o\x00s\x00 \x00<\xd8.\xdf.\x00 \x00/\x04 \x00B\x040\x04:\x046\x045\x04 \x003\x04>\x042\x04>\x04@\x04N\x04 \x00?\x04>\x04-\x00@\x04C\x04A\x04A\x04:\x048\x04.\x00'
```

Como ultimo punto, el universo de enconding es enorme y no me atrevería a explicarlo en este post. Pero por ahora lo que debes recordar es que sin importar cual uses, TIENES QUE siempre usar el mismo. Si haces enconding con utf8 entonces TIENESQUE hacer decoding con utf8. Es importante ya que si no usas el mismo, python NO mostrará error, esto puede hacer que las letras mostradas no sean las que esperabas.

Si tienes mas dudas con gusto puedo editar la resputas. Saludos y suerte :)

Comment: Eso ya lo sé, es que la pregunta era sobre porque antes se mostraban caracteres extraños, y luego si se mostraban los caracteres normales a pesar de que el código no fue modificado.

Comment: Igual fue una buena respuesta.